# Rails - Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to merge two queries in my rails app. Each one is not very complex but I can't merge them.

```
owner_packages = Package.where(owner: current_user)
admins_packages = current_user.managed_packages
@managable_packages = owner_packages.or(admins_packages)
```

user.rb

```
has_many :package_admins, dependent: :destroy
has_many :managed_packages, through: :package_admins, source: :package
```

package.rb

```
  has_many :package_admins, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :admins, through: :package_admins, source: :user
```

I'm running into this error:

> Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible
> values: [:joins]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a subselect:

```
owner_packages = Package.where(owner: current_user)
admins_packages = current_user.managed_packages
@managable_packages = owner_packages.or(Package.where(id: admins_packages))
```

This code should really be moved into the model instead of leaving all the wires hanging out:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owned_packages, class_name: 'Package',
                            foreign_key: :owner_id # just guessing here
  has_many :package_admins, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :managed_packages, through: :package_admins, source: :package


  def managable_packages 
    owned_packages.or(Package.where(id: managed_packages))
  end
end
```

An alternative method is using a union:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  # ...

  def managable_packages
    Package.from(
      owned_packages.arel.union(managed_packages.arel).as('packages')
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: This just save my day, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when you try to combine two multi-active records of the same type, but one of them has a reference value or an includes value, or in your case a joins value, that the other does not.
Therefore we need to match the values between them, and I found a general way to do this without knowing the actual values in advance.

```
admins_packages = current_user.managed_packages

owner_packages = Package.where(owner: current_user)
                        .joins(admins_packages.joins_values)
                        .includes(admins_packages.includes_values)
                        .references(admins_packages.references_values)

manageable_packages = admins_packages.or(owner_packages)
```